# CSS dropdown menu won't stay visible when you hover over the menu itself

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

Yes, I know: Many have asked this question before. For whatever reason, most of the forums with this question have different solutions. Or they seem different to me (someone who doesn't quite understand how the CSS effects work).

Anyways, I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu with CSS. When you hover over a picture of a dome, a menu should drop down. No other link should have a dropdown menu except for the picture of the dome. The dropdown menu becomes visible when you hover over the dome but disappears when you hover over the menu itself, rendering the menu useless. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<header>
<title>Ink Lit Mag</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Della+Respira' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
/*Toolbar*/
#toolbar
{
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#000000;
}
    #toolbar li
    {
     list-style-type:none;
     float:left;
    }
    #toolbarText
    {
     position:fixed;
     top:12px;
     left:100px;
     color:#ffffff;
     font-family: "Alef", sans-serif;
     font-size:20px;
    }

    #dome
    {
     position:fixed;
     top:8px;
     left:5px;
     width:28px;
     height:33.3333333333;
    }

    /*Toolbar link effects*/
    a.toolbarLink:link
    {
     color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    a.toolbarLink:hover
    {
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    a.toolbarLink:visited
    {
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    a.toolbarLink:active
    {
     color:#ffffff;
    }

/*Menu*/
#toolbar .subnav
{
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 top:50px;
 left:0px;
 width:85px;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-right:5px;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 background-color:#c0c0c0;
}

    ul#primaryNav li:hover .subnav
    {
     display:block;
    }

    /*Menu link effects*/
    a.menuLink:link
    {
     color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    a.menuLink:hover
    {
     color:#ffffff;
     background-color:#000000
    }
    a.menuLink:visited
    {
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    a.menuLink:active
    {
     color:#ffffff;
    }
</style>
</header>

<body>
<div id="toolbar">
<ul id="primaryNav">

    <li>
    <a class="toolbarLink" id="domeLink" href="http://uiowa.edu"><img id="dome" src="dome.jpg"></img></a>
        <ul class="subnav" id="subnav">
        <li><a class="menuLink" href="http://uiowa.edu">Iowa</a></li><br />
        <li><a class="menuLink" href="http://clas.uiowa.edu">CLAS</a></li><br />
        <li><a class="menuLink" href="http://magidcenter.uiowa.edu">Magid Center</a></li><br />
        </ul>
    </li>

<span id="toolbarText">
    <li><a class="toolbarLink" href="http://inklitmag.uiowa.edu">Home</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a class="toolbarLink" href="http://inklitmag.uiowa.edu/about">About</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a class="toolbarLink" href="https://inklitmag.submittable.com/submit">Submit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a class="toolbarLink" href="http://inklitmag.tumblr.com">Blink</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a class="toolbarLink" href="http://inklitmag.uiowa.edu/previousissues">Previous Issues</a></li>
</span>

</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of setting the `height:50px;` on your menu, set it on the `li` items and get rid of the height declaration on the menu. that way the menu's height will automatically expand for the submenu when it appears. right now it will remain at `50px` and when u leave that height range it is no longer activating the hover.

Comment: PlantThelda—Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I tried adding it to li, #toolbar li, ul, etc. Hasn't worked in Chrome yet. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The menu is disappearing because you are leaving the li tag when you go to scroll through the submenu.  I would change your markup to make the submenu a sub ul of the li so that the mouse is always in the li when you hover over it.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="domeLink">
    <a href="http://uiowa.edu"><img src="dome.jpg" /></a>
    <ul id="submenu">
        <li>Menu Item 1</li>
        <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul ul {
display:none;
}

#domeLink:hover > ul {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It'll stay now; I just need to figure out how to position it properly. For whatever reason, it won't work unless the positioning is static. I'd vote you up if I could, but sadly I can't.

Comment: @user1743825 no worries...glad I was able to help you out.

Comment: @user1743825 you may not be able to vote him up, but you could certainly give him credit for his answer by checking the check mark

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. 
 CSS:

```
ul#primaryNav
{
padding:0;
}

ul#primaryNav > li 
{
display:block;
height:100px;
width:50px;
}
```