# dropdown hover not staying open in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I swear I have done something this simple dropdown a million times, but for some reason IE9 doe snot want to cooperate. If you are testing it in Chrome it will work just fine, but go to IE9 and the dropdown doesn't stay open while being hovered.

At first I thought I was adding the pseudoclass :hover to the wrong element becasue itlooks like it's not catching the `<li>`, but I don't think that's it. You will notice in my code I have the submenu ul displayed none, and I am telling it later that when it gets hovered to display its submenu ul. And it does, but it goes away :(

The funky thing is, if I adjust the position of the submenu, it will work! So go figure!

1. Am I applying the pseudoclass in the wrong place?
2. If so, how come it works fine in chrome?
3. And what does the position adjustment have to do with anything?

p.s. I already checked this [CSS dropdown menu won't stay visible when you hover over the menu itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990218/css-dropdown-menu-wont-stay-visible-when-you-hover-over-the-menu-itself) out and it gave me a good direction but didn't solve my problem and the thread is kinda dead

HTML

```
<div class="blue-bar">
<div class="homepage-menu right">
    <ul>
        <li>PA STATE AGENCIES   <span class="whitecaret"></span> 
            <ul class="homepage-submenu" >  
                <a href="#"><li>Education</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Environmental Protection</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Game Commission</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Homeland Security</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Labor & Industry</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Lottery</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Public Welfare</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Revenue</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>State</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Transportation</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>More Agencies...</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>PA ONLINE SERVICES  <span class="whitecaret"></span> 

            <ul class="homepage-submenu">   
                <a href="#"><li>COMPASS: Access to Health and Human Services</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Driver & Vehicle Services</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Find a Job</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Fishing Licenses</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Homeleand Security Tip Submission</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Hunting Licenses</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Personal Income Taxes</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Places to Stay in PA</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Turnpike E-Z Pass</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Unemployment Compensation</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>More Services...</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*Home Page */

.blue-bar {
    background-color: #2a5192;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
 .homepage-menu{
z-index: 2;
height: 25px;
 }
 .homepage-menu ul {
text-align: left;
margin: 0;
display:inline;
padding: 10px 0px;
list-style: none;
font-family: "open_sanssemibold";
color: white;
 }
 .homepage-menu ul li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 2px 20px;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s;
transition: all 0.2s;
 }
 .homepage-menu ul li:hover  {
     color: #e6a61c;
 }
 .homepage-menu .whitecaret {
border-top: 6px solid white;
 }
 .homepage-menu ul li ul li {
background-color: #2a5192;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
margin: 0px 0px;
padding: 2px 10px;
width: 100%;
 }
 .homepage-menu ul li ul li:first-child {
padding-top: 15px;
 }
 .homepage-menu ul li ul li:hover {
background: #666;
 }
 ul.homepage-submenu{
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 25px; /* change this to top: 15px;*/
left: 11px;
width: 200px;
    display:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-transition: opacity 0.2s;
z-index: 1;
 }
 .homepage-menu > ul > li:hover ul{
display: block;
background-color: #2a5192;
color: white;
 }
 .whitecaret {
float: right;
position: relative;
top: -13px;
left: 10px;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
border-right: 8px solid transparent;
border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 }
```

And also a [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/FB2Fb/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that the absolutely positioned submenu has `top: 25px`. But the parent `<li>` actually just has a total height of 24px in both IE and Firefox (use Firebug/IE console to inspect). That 1px gap causes the submenu to close before you hover over it if you're not fast enough, because that gap "belongs" to neihter the relative parent `<li>` nor the absolute `<ul>`.

Just using `top: 100%` on the submenu should fix that. Also the main `<ul>` shouldn't be `display: inline`. JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/FB2Fb/9/**

To get the white caret working cross-browser use `position: absolute` on it:

```
.whitecaret {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

**Fixed up JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FB2Fb/10/**

Comment: Good job @Aleksander Bavdaz. I went to lunch, came back and was able to see the fix. But it was a bit different than yours. I did realize that the line-height vs padding was a bad practice. So when I fixed that it pushed everything up. But your solution would had fixed my problem all the same. Thanks